# Exception has occurred. MongoDartError (MongoDart Error: Invalid scheme in uri: mongodb+srv://) with flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, mongodb-atlas

Exception has occurred.

> MongoDartError (MongoDart Error: Invalid scheme in uri:
>   mongodb+srv://:@epawn-gfiev.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
>   mongodb+srv)

I am using mongo_dart 0.3.6 https://pub.dev/packages/mongo_dart#-readme-tab-

```
 Db db = new Db("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_dart-blog");
 await db.open();
```

to connect ATLAS mongodb, but facing the error above, anyone can advice about this issues?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you add an IP Address if using Cloud Atlas
2. "**mongo_dart-blog"** if databases are created, otherwise:

   ```
   Db.create("mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo_dart-blog");
   ```
3. For connecting to MongoDB, use a blocking statement:

   ```
   await Db.create("mongodb://usaername:pass ---- /mongo_dart-blog");
   ```